How to Retrieve Subscription Details for Orders Using WooCommerce PHP REST API?
I'm in the process of importing orders from a WooCommerce store that includes subscription products. I need assistance with retrieving subscription details for a the orders via the WooCommerce PHP REST API.
Specifically, I'm looking for information such as the next billing date and the subscription status (active or not).

I am able to import orders.
The order subscription details is missing in the Order API response.
This is a sample meta-data in the response:

    ...... 
    'meta_data' =>    array (
         0 => 
         array (
           'id' => 'aaaaa',
           'key' => 'pa_color',
           'value' => 'black',
           'display_key' => 'Color',
           'display_value' => 'Black',
         ),
         1 => 
         array (
           'id' => 'bbbbb',
           'key' => 'pa_wrist-size',
           'value' => 'medium',
           'display_key' => 'Band / Wrist Size',
           'display_value' => 'Medium',
         ),
         2 => 
         array (
           'id' => 'ccccc',
           'key' => 'pa_payment-options',
           'value' => 'annual-plan',
           'display_key' => 'Plan Options',
           'display_value' => 'Annual Plan',
         ),   ), 
        ......   
    'payment_method' => 'stripe', 
    ......

I attempted to use the WooCommerce Subscriptions API with the endpoint $store_url/wp-json/wc/v1/subscriptions/$subscription_id, where $subscription_id is ccccc. This ID corresponds to the annual plan details found in the metadata. However, I got subscription details not found error.
Could someone guide me on which endpoint to use to obtain the order subscription information?
Appreciate any help!

In your array response, "ccccc" is the order item meta ID for Payment options attribute, but not the subscription ID. I don't know how to get the related subscription via rest API, but in the database, the subscription can be found via the parent ID, which is the related order.
